# Username problem

Tags: username

Whenever I go to the terminal, and try and do something, it says `username@hostlocal`. And I have no clue what to do.

I looks like this:

```
(precise) spencerstreams@hostlocal:~$:
```

Comment: That is the name of your computer, you can change it if you want to. What are you trying to do at the terminal? What is the terminal telling you when you do it? What do you get when you type `hostname` in the terminal? Is it `hostlocal` or something else?

Comment: So what's the problem here?

Comment: @kelvin that `(precise)` makes it look like the prompt from a chroot or a virtualenv (run `debian_chroot=precise bash` on Ubuntu to see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That's your username and computer name. It's analogous to the `C:\Users\username` that is shown in the Windows command prompt and powershell consoles.

Now, that being said, I don't see what the problem is in your question. Please clarify it out.

For more information about what the terminal is, and how its used, [check here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)